# Источники данный в Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Доброго времени суток! На работе периодически возникает необходимость мелких форм для вноса данных, в проектах обычно использую связку access+dataset\oledbcommand, и вот вчера мне сказали что dataset прошлый век:) я в общем то не претендую на программиста,просто интересно что сейчас актуальной в плане хранения данных в мелких проектах, на что стоит обратить внимание и куда копать ?

Comment: Поинтересуйтесь у тех кто вам такое сказал что они считают HI-End в этой области. Вполне возможно, что access они предложат заменить на SQLlite что, по сути, то же самое или, например, XML а может ещё что-то. Диапазон вариантов колеблется от txt файла до локальной БД. И все эти варианты стары как мир. Если что и появляется нового, так это способы защиты этих файлов, но это уже немного другая тема.

Comment: можно заменить топор на бензопилу, топор-то этож прошлое тысячелетие, только вот что вы будете делать в лесу с бензопилой без топлива, да и весит она раз так во много больше? Выбирайте средства исходя из потребностей и возможностей, а не за модность, современность и красивое название. ИМХО разумеется.

Comment: Мне советовали использовать связку Compact SQL+Entity. Мой вопрос в большей степени относился к вопросу о простоте реализации и возможность масштабировать своё приложение. Ну да ладно:)

Comment: если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про альтернативу Access можно почитать в этом топике [What is a good choice of database for a small .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749556/what-is-a-good-choice-of-database-for-a-small-net-application)

А если интересует, чем можно заменить Dataset, то можно посмотреть в сторону различных [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), таких как [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx) или [NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/), или в сторону MicroORM, как пример [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: Спасибо! Данная информация - это именно то,что я и хотел получить!